# Rendering components in Seaside: Improve upon a metaphor for the flow from WARenderer >> render: to WAComponent >> renderContentOn:

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

I need help understanding the flow from `WARenderer >> render:` to `WAComponent >> renderContentOn:` when a **renderer** is sent the `#render:` message with a **component** as argument in **Seaside** (the Smalltalk web framework).

Like this: `aRenderer render: aComponent`.

I am trying to capture intuition about how components and renderers play together for rendering in Seaside. So, I started with the recommended way to go about rendering:

`aRenderer render: aComponent`

And went along with the chain of executions that follow, starting from `WARenderer >> render:`.

I have been able to come up with a metaphor to help me understand the flow. The metaphor is in the form of a conversation between objects. However, this metaphor is not quite complete. There's a gulf right in the middle of it which I need help filling up.

Here goes the metaphor.

`myRenderer render: myComponent.`

**myR**: Hey, component, I believe you know best how to render yourself on any renderer. Could you render yourself on me?

`myComponent renderOn: myRenderer.`

**myC**: Sure! I'm going to need some context for this rendering though.

`myComponent renderWithContext: myRenderer context.`

**myR**: So, you want context? Well context is what you get!

`myComponent renderWithContext: aRenderContext.`

***the gulf I need help filling exists at this point***

`aRenderContext visitor visit: myComponent.`

***and maybe at this point as well***

`aRenderVisitor visit: myComponent.`

**aRV**: Ping! You home? Can I come around?

`myComponent accept: aRenderVisitor.`

**myC**: Yeah. Come around, already!

`aRenderVisitor visitPainter: myComponent.`

**aRV**: Okay, be there in a jiffy!

Then, in `RenderVisitor >> visitPainter:`:

- a renderer is *recreated* (by myComponent) using the context of this rendering (obtained from aRenderVisitor),
- `WAComponent >> renderContentOn:` is invoked on myComponent with the so-created renderer as argument, and
- then the renderer is flushed.

That's the metaphor. I can work with it as it is. But I'll be grateful if someone could help plug in the holes and beat it into shape.